# Unable to obtain case-sensitive results from elasticsearch URI query

Tags: elasticsearch

The documentation here:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

Reads to me, like I would be able to do this:
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9333/articles/_search?pretty&lowercase_expanded_terms:false&q=slug:31Ux"

And receive the exact case-sensitive match on the slug field

Instead my results turn out to be:
        "slug" : "31uX",
        "slug" : "31Ux",
        "slug" : "31ux",
        "slug" : "31UX"

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a case sensitive analyzer when creating the index. By default, the mapping should be case insensitive as the standard analyzer indexes in lowercases.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Comment: Ok thank you, but I don't understand how to create the case-sensitive analyzer on that field, if you could please provide an example for me to map to my index that would be really helpful!